# Dango & Vue.Js project

Tags: django, vue.js, architecture

I've been building a lot of test websites in Django, and took an online course in Django + Vue.JS, but I'm not 100% comfortable yet (with Vue.js and bigger projects). So I have a question.

First a small description about my idea;
I want a basic home page, just some information about my service, with some additional pagel about, learn, products, etc. You get it.
Then there has to be a user register/login section. I've created one before with an email verification, but I also want to add a monthly payment (any tips/tutorials are welcome).

After you've registered and logged in, you have to be redirected to the Web-App I want to build.

In the web-app I want to build a few different apps, let's say; I want to build a stock analyse app. Where every analysing tool has other calculations, etc.

The question I have;
How does the architecture of the app should look like?
Should I have a home-app, user-app, stock-app?

Where only the stock-app has to be combined with Vue.js, how to make this happen?

And how to make sure only logged in users can access the web-app? Or is this possible with
@login_required?

Hope someone can give me an example or something, because I'm a little stuck on this one.

Cheers guys!

Answer (score 0):

You should go with JWT token. Keycloak is an open source option. I would go like this,

1. Create users in Keycloak.
2. Authenticate users using Keycloak.
3. For authenticated user, front end will receive JWT token. This token contains info about authentication and authorization.
4. Send this token in each request to backend. Backend will authenticate each request and return a response.

See https://jwt.io/introduction